# UV mesh is distorted, not a reliable representation of the model?

Tags: uv

Im working on a face model, trying to create a single 2d printable image of the face's texture.
I created the desireable uv layout, used the texture paint tool- stencil brush in order to create the texture. 
Now, after printing the result, I realised that the UV layout that the Blender created does not represent the model in the correct way. I know that after realising that the both parts of the same seams are significantly not in the same size, although these lines are the line in the 3D model.
I realised that there are two kinds of UV unwrapping methods, but I couldn't find any information on the subject, not in stackexchage and not on different manuals on the net.
What is the cause of this distortion? Can the UV unwrap setting fix it?
Thank you in advance
[image: I hope these photo describes well the distortion Im speaking of]

Comment: It's a little difficult to tell what you're asking. Are you asking "Why is the UV layout on the left different from the UV layout on the right?"

Comment: @D Brown: uv mapping scope is to represent in 2d what is in 3d, so sometimes some faces can look distorted in 2d,  and if you already painted you model, the distorted texture in 2d looks "different" from what you see in 3d. But the point is that once that 2d texture is mapped back on 3d, it will look as you intended, while painting it. Just paint on the 3d texture, not on the 2d texture. And, adding seams can help to prevent distorting

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [paper model export add-on](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Paper_Model), it seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i think your going into a wrong workflow.
If you got the face model.
use seams, to to cut areas for a 'reasonable'fitting UV layout.
So you could split in a front and back, and left / right.
and make seam for example around the ears so they wont distort the unfolding.

Next inside blender create a new image as texture, use blender to paint the texture, and make sure to save your texture.

UV layout are not like origami layouts, but i believe there does exist an adon so you could manually fold a face, but not sure why you would need that.